# What compiler switches make the life of a reverse engineer harder/easier?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation

Let's consider the VC++ 2013 compiler. What compiler switches make the life of a reverse engineer harder/easier? Does the compiler add any meta-information to help determine the origin of the executable?

Comment: How about the documentation? And don´t rely on switches alone. Obfuscator etc.etc.

Comment: not shipping the debug version of the program might be a good start.

Comment: every switch that sounds like "stripping" "removing" "optimizing" etc

Comment: Don't ship the .pdbs.  They give out a lot of information about the program.  Re origin of the executable - you can add that with the version attribute in an .rc file.  If you use dumpbin /all on the executable, you can see what information is available.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to Visual-C++: Any switch that increases the probability of code transformation decreases the amount of reverse-engineerability. Most particualarly, those are all optimization switches (but note that in case of g++, the `-O`-family of switches are really collections of many other switches).

E.g., if you have

```
int foo() {
    return 3;
}

int main () {
    std::cout << (foo()*foo()) << '\n';
}
```

and the compiler transforms this into (here: inlining)

```
int main () {
    std::cout << (3*3) << '\n';
}
```

and then into (here: constant folding)

```
int main () {
    std::cout << 9 << '\n';
}
```

it should be apparent that it will be impossible to extract the original `foo` function.